# ImageMagick Go API HTTP Hangs on ReadImageBlob

Tags: go, docker, imagemagick, freeze, beego

I have written an Beego HTTP server, that when a user hits an endpoint:

- the server requests an image from another server (for instance imgur)
- it reads the bytes of the image and passes them to [gographics/imagick](http://github.com/gographics/imagick)
- this (should) resize the image and return the byte array of the result

what actually happens is my HTTP server completely hangs, I don't even get to the error handling, and I get a 502 bad gateway on all endpoints of the server.

My code looks like this:

```
func processContactImage(idx int, image []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    imagick.Initialize()
    defer imagick.Terminate()
    log.Println("idx: ", idx)
    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()

    log.Println("reading image blob: ", image)
    err := mw.ReadImageBlob(image)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("reading blob failed: ", err)
        return []byte{}, err
    }
//...
}
```

I can see in the terminal the log message "reading image blob: [bytes, bytes bytes]" and I have copied the bytes printed to another small program to test the bytes do indeed hold an image, they do.
It completely hangs on `err := mw.ReadImageBlob(image)` and I don't think it even gets into the `if err != nil` as I never see that log message.

Tips on how I should debug this would be welcome. I have written a small program to test the image magick funtions work on the byte array in a standalone enviroment, and it all works fine.

My thoughts:

- I don't completely understand how Go handles stack/heap, I thought it was able to move things to the heap if necessary and I didn't need to manage this. However I am storing an image in memory, I thought perhaps `seg fault` but Im not sure why it doesn't crash but hangs...
- `ReadImageBlob` is expecting a type of image data, and its not getting it, although I would have then thought it got to the error

**EDIT:**

OK thanks for comments, after more research, it seems like it is related to the fact I am running this in Docker, it hadn't occured that this could be an issue however:

1. I have moved the initialization of imagemagick to main and the error still occurs
2. When I run the application without docker, and I pass a byte array to the handler, imagemagick code runs fine.
3. When I attach to the docker container, add a small test program that adds a circle to an image using imagemagick (however not a web service, just a binary) it works, albeit very slowly

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.7-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add git && apk add g++ && apk add bzr && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# ENV GOPATH /go

# Install beego & bee
RUN go get github.com/astaxie/beego
RUN go get github.com/beego/bee
RUN go get github.com/tools/godep

RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk
RUN apk add imagemagick-dev
RUN go get gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick
```

I wonder if I am missing a library or something and its hanging inside the C api and Go is waiting for a response. Is there any way I can debug this?

OK... As it turns out the issue is something else... perhaps multiple requests at once or something... I'm not sure, but I have created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/amlwwalker/a3ee1639dc5e32fad8a16aa085524917) demonstrating using imagemagick, in Go, in a handler, and it works locally no problem inside my docker container. The mystery continues....

Comment: Get a stack trace to show exactly where everything is blocked. You can also make a small standalone program that calls `ReadImageBlob(image)` on the exact same input.

Comment: Any tips on how to force a stacktrace?

Comment: Send the process a `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: Go does automatically promote objects to the heap if it detects an escape. `ReadImageBlob` expects a normal `[]byte`.

Comment: Have you tried the setup in an alternate base docker image, like a full Ubuntu or something? Curious if it is specific to the minimal alpine image.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this in your handler:

```
imagick.Initialize()
defer imagick.Terminate()
```

That is only supposed to be done once, in your `main()`

Most likely you are conflicting with different requests, by tearing down the entire ImageMagick each time a request finishes.

Comment: Ok I moved this, and the error continued, so I ran more tests and I currently believe the error is docker related, I have updated original question

Comment: I see. Well I can't say I have any experience running imagick within a docker setup. Although I am puzzled as to why it makes a difference, unless its related to some kind of limitation in the environment. I've run imagick in a web based service that processed images per request and served tons of requests without issue. Albeit not in a dockerized situation.

Answer (score 0):

Nice one @jdi it was something to do with Alpine...

Below are my two docker files, the first, with Alpine @612MB doesn't work, it hangs when imagemagick tries to read the blob. The second with golang:latest and 931MB works. I'm not sure why, but it does solve my problem.

Thanks I hope this helps someone else!

```
FROM golang:1.7-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add git && apk add g++ && apk add bzr && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN go get github.com/astaxie/beego
RUN go get github.com/beego/bee
RUN go get github.com/tools/godep

RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk
RUN apk add imagemagick-dev
RUN go get gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick
```

and the second:

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qy \
        pkg-config \
        libmagickcore-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        imagemagick \
        git \
        g++ \
        bzr \

    #clear up
    && apt-get autoremove && \
    apt-get autoclean && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* 

RUN go get gopkg.in/gographics/imagick.v2/imagick
RUN go get github.com/astaxie/beego
RUN go get github.com/beego/bee
RUN go get github.com/tools/godep
```

Comment: Sweet. Well alpine obviously either has some kind of conflicting default configuration or missing something needed by the fact that imagick is a cgo binding and causes your app to become dynamically linked